# The image you are trying to upload has invalid dimensions. Please change your image to match the required upload dimensions and try again

Tags: facebook, image, file-upload

I am trying to upload an image in the "app icon" of facebooks developers page. I verified the images I was upload was within 1024 x 1024 and 5mb. I tried upload as jpg and png. Every time I try I am getting "The image you are trying to upload has invalid dimensions. Please change your image to match the required upload dimensions and try again." How can I fix this?

Comment: If you have found the solution by now please answer your own question, because I'm experiencing the same error right now and do not know what to do.

Comment: Use this [website](https://onlinepngtools.com/resize-png) to make sure it is exactly 1024 x 1024. **Note**: Make sure you untick `Preserve Ratio`

Answer (score 1):

The picture has to be exactly 1024 x 1024 and under 5mb. Also see the guidelines here on the icon

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/appcenter/guidelines#icons

Comment: My image is 1024x1024 and it still won't let me?

Answer (score 0):

Your app icon has to be exactly 1024x1024 px. First export your icon (png or jpg) in high resolution and then open that file in paint. Select resize option in home tab and select pixel radio button then enter 1024px x 1024px and save it.
It will work.